# Tensorflow - loss not decreasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Lately, I have been trying to replicate the results of [this post](https://medium.com/@tuennermann/convolutional-neural-networks-to-find-cars-43cbc4fb713), but using TensorFlow instead of Keras. However, my model loss is not converging as [in the code provided](https://github.com/HTuennermann/Vehicle-Detection-and-Tracking). I took care to use the same parameters used by the author, even those not explicitly shown. My complete code can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/arnaldog12/2f6e8910f56a73e95be682143193682e).

I have already tried different learning rates, optimizers, and batch sizes, but these did not affect the result very much as well.

I found a bunch of other questions related to this problem here in StackOverflow and StackExchange, but most of them had no answer at all. The questions with answers, however, did not help.

I'm using TensorFlow 1.1.0,  Python 3.6 and Windows 10.

The most weird thing is that we have the same database and the same model, but just different frameworks. Thus, it was not supposed to give completely different behaviours. Does anyone have suggestions about what should I try to solve this problem, please?

Comment: Short comment: you should be using "`is_training`" to disable dropout during testing. Further, it seems like your network always outputs zeroes, so the gradients are worthless. Have you tried disabling dropout?

Comment: why is your loss mean squared error and why is tanh the activation for something you're calling "logits"  ?

Comment: You're right, @JonasAdler, I was not using dropout since "is_training" default value is False, so my output was untouched. I tried to set it true now, but the problem still happens.

Comment: @RyanStout, I'm using exactly the same model, loss and optimizer as in [the post](https://medium.com/@tuennermann/convolutional-neural-networks-to-find-cars-43cbc4fb713) I mentioned. I'm also afraid that tanh is vanishing the gradients, but it's weird that it not working in Tensorflow.

Comment: People often use cross entropy error when performing binary classification, but this will work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran your code basically unmodified, but I looked at the shape of your tf_labels and logits and they're not the same. logits had shape (batch_size,1,1,1) (because you were using a 1x1 convolutional filter) and tf_labels had shape (batch_size,1). I changed your loss line to be

```
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(tf.squeeze(tf_labels),
           tf.squeeze(logits)))
```

and the loss decreased each epoch.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Ryan. It worked! I lost the last 2 weeks trying to minimize the loss using other known methods, but the error was related to a totally different thing. Thanks for showing me what and why it happened. I will vote your answer up as soon as I have enough reputation points.

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem. I was using cross entropy loss in regression problem which was not correct. This mean squared loss worked perfectly.